# JSON schema array required

Tags: arrays, json, jsonschema

I'm trying to figure out how to set a global-level array required in schema. My example JSON file is:

```
[
    {
        "firstname": "Paul",
        "lastname": "McCartney"
    },
    {
        "firstname": "John",
        "lastname": "Lennon"
    },
    {
        "firstname": "George",
        "lastname": "Harrison"
    },
    {
        "firstname": "Ringo",
        "lastname": "Starr"
    }
]
```

As seen above, I want the top-level structure to be an array, not an object. The schema I've got from jsonschema.net is (with slight modifications):

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "id": "/",
  "type": "array",
  "items": {
    "id": "elements",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "firstname": {
        "id": "firstname",
        "type": "string"
      },
      "lastname": {
        "id": "lastname",
        "type": "string"
      }
    },
    "required": [
      "firstname",
      "lastname"
    ]
  },
  "required": [
    "/"
  ]
}
```

But it fails with the [jsonschema validator](https://github.com/tdegrunt/jsonschema). Can you please help me with providing correct JSON schema for top-level array?

Comment: You don't need to make the top-level thing required.  If the document is an array, then the document isn't optional!  If you're trying to specify a minimum number of items, try `minItems`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be valid with your input data you just need following schema:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "type": "array",
    "id": "http://jsonschema.net",
    "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
        "firstname": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "lastname": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "required": [
        "firstname",
        "lastname"
    ]}
}
```

Comment: hmm, I get it - I had useless top-level `required` field defined. The array-element-level `required` is enough. Perfect, thanks!

Comment: i am using `check-jsonschema` and `required` should be a field OF `items`, not on the same level WITH `items`